# Setting cursor coordinates to iPad coordinates?

Tags: ipad, cursor

Is there a way to make it so when the user touches the iPad that it makes location where the user touches the iPad the same as where cursor is on the computer?

Comment: This doesn't even make any sense. What computer are you talking about?

Comment: @Orion Edwards: I mean a typical old computer. For example, a Macbook would be a computer or a Mac Pro or something like that.

Comment: OK so let me get this straight: You have an iPad, and sitting next to it a Mac. When the user touches the screen on the iPad, you want to ask the mac what it's mouse co-ordinates are (say 200,300), and then tell the iPad "No, don't click where you're supposed to, click at 200,300 instead" - That seems insane

Comment: @Orion Edwards: No, when the user touches the iPad it changes the current mouse coordinates of the computer to the coordinates of the iPad touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the basic question, yes it is possible. Take a look at the various VNC clients out there.

If you're wanting to implement this yourself, you'll need to get the coordinates on the iPad's screen (shouldn't be that hard), then using a network connection, send that information to a program running on the mac, and that program will take the coordinates (either as an absolute X,Y position, or as a % of the position on the screen) and move the mouse on the OS X machine.